# Mongoid one-to-many relation query in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, mongodb-query

I am using Mongoid in Ruby on Rails and have created two models using the following definition:

```
class Conversation
    include Mongoid::Document

    field :ctopic
    belongs_to :tag
end

class Tag
    include Mongoid::Document

    field :name, type: String
    has_many :conversations
end
```

What I want to do is to get all the conversations that has the specified tag. For example, there is a tag whose name is 'Closed', I want to get all the conversations whose tag is 'Closed'.

I have tried the two following approaches but all failed:

**Approach 1:**

```
convs = Tag.where(name: component).Conversation.all()
```

It turned out to be a grammar mistake since it could not compile successfully

**Approach 2:**

```
my_tag = Tag.where(name: component)
convs = Conversation.where(tag: my_tag)
```

Could not get conversation objects successfully.

Does anyone have a feasible way to fulfill my goal? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get all the conversations for a specific tag using one of the following

```
# approach 1
Tag.where(name: 'some_name').include(:conversations).each do |conversation|
  # you have the conversation here
end

# approach 2
convs = Conversation.where(tag_id: "SOME_BSON_ID_OF_THE_TAG").to_a

# approach 3
my_tag = Tag.where(name: component).first
my_tag.conversations

# approach 4
my_conv = Conversation.where(ctopic: 'some_value').first
my_conv.tag.conversations
```

you can also refer to [Mongoid docs](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html) for full reference on how to query mongoid models

Comment: Thanks. I found approach 2 satisfy me needs, since it allows for multiple collections join query.